# Are questions by amateurs welcome on Economics Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

In the self-description of the site, "Economics Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for professional and academic economists and analysts". I have no qualifications or employment in the field of economics. Nevertheless, I am fascinated by the subject. In particular, I have some specific and well-defined, albeit perhaps naive, questions that professional economists could probably answer well. Would such questions be welcome here?

Answer (score 5):

We mostly guard against questions that we not well-defined or spefic (like this monster: https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/10508/which-site-to-look-for-complete-economic-knowledge). But specific and well-defined questions from non-specialists are welcome.

Here are some examples of questions that could have been (and in some cases were) asked by an amateur, but that were well-received by the community:

[What has caused the recent 25% unemployment rate in Spain?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/what-has-caused-the-recent-25-unemployment-rate-in-spain/1809#1809)

[How does a country devalue its currency?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/6875/how-does-a-country-devalue-its-currency/6883#6883)

[How can the Swiss exchange rate be very biased in a free market?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/5054/how-can-swiss-francs-exchange-rate-be-that-much-biased-in-a-free-market/5055#5055)

[How does Black Friday work?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/9531/how-does-black-friday-work/9553#9553)

[Is UK house price spiral connected to debt based monetary system?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/is-uk-house-price-spiral-connected-to-debt-based-monetary-system/5372#5372)

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say ex-ante. They're definitely on-topic, but they might not be highly appreciated. See Ubi's list of questions that were.

I have no problem with beginner level questions, but I find it harder to answer questions when I cannot expect familiarity with economics terminology on the other side. See for example [this question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/10322/why-dont-burgers-cost-5-cents/10355#10355).

None of these answers to that question are easily understandable without a minimum (undergraduate) working knowledge of economics. And they're not intended to be, it simply is out of the scope to define and introduce every concept in every answer.

If you have enough of a familiarity with the terminology to digest the answers (or willingness to read up on them on your own), asking your questions here can be fruitful.